# It is necessary to have a specific mail program installed to use PHP mail() to send an email?

Tags: php, email, ubuntu

This question may be redundant but I'm trying to figure out if it is necessary to install a separate mail server (Sendmail, postfix etc.) on the server just to send out an email using php's mail().

I'm just trying to send out an email, don't need to receive.

I'm running a `Ubuntu 12.4` box with `PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2`.

Comment: Yes you need a mail server to send outgoing mail.

Comment: PHP by default simply invokes 'sendmail'. Postfix/Exim both supply a symlink which maps sendmail to themselves, so you don't actually NEED to have sendmail installed, just a mail server that can masquerade as sendmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On any platform other than Windows, yes it is necessary.  PHP simply executes sendmail, or equivalent.

Windows is a bit different.  The PHP folks conveniently allow sending to an SMTP server on Windows.

Comment: What about using an internal exchange server on the same network to send out, would that work; if so what should I google?

Comment: Sure, just open up Exchange for SMTP.  Configure PHP.ini to point to your Exchange SMTP server.

Comment: Can I do that without installing a mail server? Also the first server that has the PHP mail() is Ubuntu 12.4 and the other exchange 2007 on SBS2008. Both on the same internal network.

Answer (score 0):

You may use postfix's sendmail.

You can find a lot of "howto" helping you installing it.